# Cut out a piece of text from a string contained between specific elements (jquery/javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I have been trying to modify a string. Getting the content included inside, removing a piece of it, and copying that text as a *alt* attribute of the paragraph itself. I decided to start the text which has to be cut by ([ and finish it by ]) So everything inside it, must be cut out and pasted as a alt attribute. It looks really easy, but I could not find a way on JQuery (preferable) or Javascript, but I know that there must be a way.

In this link (http://jsfiddle.net/MYbuddy/6psR2/) you can see a flowchart that I have just developed. The flowchart is auto created using a list with a specific class applied (.flowchart) and inside of the elements is the text I would have to cut.

```
<li>list 01 01 01 ([This text must be removed and copied as "alt" or "title" text])</li>
```

The html you will see on the link is exactly the HTML I get straight from umbraco, and I can't modify it too much (like adding specific styles) that why I did some "rare" things with my script, hehe.

I hope it all makes sense for you guys.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use this jquery:

```
$('.flowchart li > p').each(function () {
     var $this = $(this),        //store this so we can use it later
         txt = $this.text(),     //this is the current text value
         lText = txt.split('['); //this is splitting the text at the '['

     $this.attr({ title: ""+lText[1] }); //here we are setting the title to lText[1] which is the text AFTER the split
     $this.text(lText[0]);               //here we are setting the current text to lText[0] which is the text BEFORE the split
});
```

it will split the text at the `[` that will be added to the title, then the text will be set as the first part of the text.
if possible, you should change your text so that you only get the `[` and not the `([ text  ])` otherwise you will only need more code to remove it.

here is a link to the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6psR2/4/

here is an extended version which will split the start and end:

```
  $('.flowchart li > p').each(function () {
       var $this = $(this),
       txt = $this.text(),
       lText = txt.split('['),
       rText = txt.split(']');

            if (typeof rText[0] === "undefined")
                {rText[0] = ""}  
            if (typeof rText[1] === "undefined")
                {rText[1] = ""}  
            if (typeof lText[0] === "undefined")
                {lText[0] = ""} 
            if (typeof lText[1] === "undefined")
                {lText[1] = ""} 
            $this.attr({ title: lText[1]+"" });
            $this.text(lText[0]+" "+rText[1]);
    });
```

It will also check that the string value is not undefined, if it is, then it will set to an empty string to save adding "undefined" as a title.

Comment: Thanks wf4. It wasn't exactly what I wanted, because I was expecting to be able to set the beginning and the end of the text to cut out, so there would be no mistakes when somebody is typing the text for it.
But I think I will take it this way, hehe.

Comment: I can do that for you if you like, it's not too much more. I'm on my mobile just now but I'll fire up my laptop and will update my answer for you soon. :-)

Comment: Woho, man. So clever @wf4 ! Thanks a million for your help. **That is exactly what I was looking for**, and I didn't even think about split twice with different characters and then merging them. In just in few lines of code, **that's great**. Thanks :D

Comment: I suppose it was something you missed, but it was still saving as title everything after the first [ I just had to add a line before:
`$this.attr({ title: lText[0]+"" });`

That simple line I added was a variable to getting the array from a split of lText[1] (inside it was saving everything after the first [ )
`var titleText = lText[1].split(']');`

And it just works great :D I have updated the code on JSFiddle, so you can check it: http://jsfiddle.net/MYbuddy/6psR2/7/
Thanks again.